# Php case insensitive word replacement from a sentence

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I need to replace the matching words from a sentence. I am using the below but it's case sensitive. I need case insensitive.

```
$originalString  = 'This is test.';
$findString = "is";
$replaceWith = "__";

$replacedString = (str_ireplace($findString, $replaceWith, $originalString));
// output : Th__ __ test.
```

Then I've tried

```
$replacedString = preg_replace('/\b('.preg_quote($findString).')\b/', $replaceWith, $originalString);
// output : This __ test.
```

It's working fine as expected but if i use `$findString = "Is"` or `"iS"` or `"IS"` then it's not working.
Can anybody suggest me what will be the regex. to get case insensitive replacement or any other way to achieve the desire result.

> UPDATED

As per `@nu11p01n73R` answer I have changed below but in below example it's get fall.

```
$originalString  = 'Her (III.1) was the age of 2 years and 11 months. (shoulder a 4/5)';
$findStringArray = array("age", "(III.1)", "2", "months", "4");
foreach($findStringArray as $key => $value) {
    $originalString = preg_replace('/\b('.preg_quote($value).')\b/i', "__", $originalString);
}
//Output : Her (III.1) was the __ of __ years and 11 __. (shoulder a __/5)

//Output should be : Her __ was the __ of __ years and 11 __. (shoulder a 4/5)
```

And also it's stopped working if I add `4/5` on `$findStringArray`

Comment: It looks then, like you're trying to replace entire words (ie the string exploded on a space " " ) only, not a subset within a word, is this correct?

Comment: Actually I need to highlight the text

Comment: ok, the question is, whatever you need to do, is it only to entire "words"?  Because in your example you want to hightlight "4", if you want to highlight it it ANYWHERE in the text, @nu11p01n73R's answer is exceptional, if only "words" then a slightly modified version would be required...

Comment: No I don't want to highlight `4` because in the string it's not `4` it's `4/5`.

Comment: Down voters why down vote me??

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to add an [**ignore case modifier `i`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to the end of the regex as

```
$originalString  = 'This Is test.';
$findString = "is";
$replaceWith = "__";
$replacedString = preg_replace('/\b('.preg_quote($findString).')\b/i', $replaceWith, $originalString);
// output : This __ test.
```

Comment: @TapasPal There some very small things that missed.
1. `\b\(III.1\)\b` is different from `\(\bIII.1\b\)`. The latter only will match `III.1`
2. The `\b` contains `, . / ( )` etc so when `4` in `4/5` will be matched by `\b4\b`.

Comment: So whats needs to change?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use word boundary with `(III.1)`  or `4/5`, have a try with:

```
$originalString  = 'Her (III.1) was the age of 2 years and 11 months. (shoulder a 4/5)';
$findStringArray = array("age", "(III.1)", "2", "months", "4/5");
foreach($findStringArray as $key => $value) {
    $originalString = preg_replace('~(?<=^|[. (])'.preg_quote($value).'(?=[. )]|$)~i', "__", $originalString);
    //                            __^       __^                            __^  __^
}
echo $originalString,"\n";
```

**Edit:** I've changed the delimiter from `/` to `~` and added parenthesis in the lookaround.

**Output:**

```
Her __ was the __ of __ years and 11 __. (shoulder a __)
```

Comment: Sorry bro it's still stopped working if I add `4/5` on `$findStringArray`

Comment: @TapasPal: What is the wanted result with `4/5`?

Comment: output should be `Her __ was the __ of __ years and 11 __. (shoulder a __)`